# jQuery/Javascript Interactive Timezone Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I have had a look at: http://jvectormap.com/

And I want to do something similar myself, basically a world map with distinct zones (for timezones) which when moused over go maybe a shade grayer, and obviously carry a value associated.

However, I am completely confused on how I can do this.

I have heard of SVG and tried one or two things out but if someone could please point me in the right direction I would gladly be helpful.

Normally I wouldn't ask such a mundane question but I am really puzzled here.

Comment: What is your question? If it is about how to use jQuery SVG, I suggest looking at the questions that show up in the "Related" sidebar on the right.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this question:

[Timezonepicker](http://timezonepicker.com/?w=1024&base=gray) is a very nice solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/). The second demo (President demo) shows how you can hover over an object outside the map to highlight regions in the map.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely give this a try as well as some other things and post back with my solution.